# zfs-import-cache.service failed after upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10

Tags: upgrade, zfs, 20.10

Because of that the /root pool is not loading and subsequently zsys fails.

systemctl status zfs-import-cache :

```
● zfs-import-cache.service - Import ZFS pools by cache file
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-03 18:03:47 PST; 21min ago
       Docs: man:zpool(8)
   Main PID: 2299 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 03 18:03:46 i7-7820x systemd[1]: Starting Import ZFS pools by cache file...
Nov 03 18:03:46 i7-7820x zpool[2299]: cannot import 'lxd': no such pool or dataset
Nov 03 18:03:47 i7-7820x zpool[2299]:         Destroy and re-create the pool from
Nov 03 18:03:47 i7-7820x zpool[2299]:         a backup source.
Nov 03 18:03:47 i7-7820x systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Main process exited, code=exited>
Nov 03 18:03:47 i7-7820x systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 03 18:03:47 i7-7820x systemd[1]: Failed to start Import ZFS pools by cache file.
```

Any ideas how to debug or fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I experienced the same issue,

I found a way to solve it by adding a delay to the ZFS modules when the `init-ramfs` is loading

my system is an AWS EC2 instance with

```bsh
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

import your ZFS tank again
`sudo zpool import -f $TANK_NAME`

open the file **/etc/default/zfs** and add the value `ZFS_INITRD_PRE_MOUNTROOT_SLEEP='4'`

execute the command and then reboot

```bsh
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u

sudo reboot
```

You tank is imported now after reboot.
`zfs list`

Answer (score 0):

The delay, suggested by Andre Leon Rangel, didn't help in my case.

Updated the service to run `zpool import` before importing cached pools.
Just wanted to check logs and see which were available.

Somehow, adding that magically solved the issue without need for the delay.